# D3 add stroke to the side of a path only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm creating a path that's following an arch along a donut chart. It's rendering 12 paths which make up my entire donut. I'm trying to figure out how to only have stroke along the left and right side of each path. One of my paths looks like this (the rest on this loop sit next to it).

```
<path stroke-width="0.4" fill="none" d="M-124.0972400982391,-124.09724009823911A175.50000000000003,175.50000000000003,0,0,1,45.422742415492394,-169.51998251373152L42.705142441915925,-159.37776133769628A165,165,0,0,0,-116.67261889578033,-116.67261889578035Z" stroke="#EAEDED"></path>
```

in d3 it looks like

```js
const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  const graph = new Array(6).fill(1); // 6 equal sections

  const gridPie = d3
    .pie()
    .startAngle(startAngle)
    .endAngle(endAngle)
    .sort(null)
    .value(d => d);

  const arc = d3
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * innerFactor)
    .outerRadius(radius * outerFactor);

  svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(gridPie(graph))
    .join("path")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0.4)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("stroke", "#EAEDED")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Here is the codesandbox to the project I am working on. The area in question can be found on line 84 of wheel.js file.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-haze-rzpz2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: can you add a working snippet, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: You may try to use stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset, For example in the case of the path in your example you may try to use `stroke-dasharray = "377.57" stroke-dashoffset="194"`. However it would be nice to understand what you have in mind. I have the filling that you can do it in a much simpler way

Comment: Hi, I've added an image as well as a code sandbox link to what I am working on, hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have this same exact issue and what I've found is because D3 animates rect objects inside only one svg you don't get all the styling options available, you can only add the border to all sides. My thought is to add a rect element in when d3 fires on page load but haven't got this to work yet.

Comment: I've solutions for rects to include dasharray and creating a filter element but I'm using a path to generate an arc so I'm not sure how well these solutions translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by removing the stroke from the path and instead appending lines to the ends of my arcs. In my case I needed every other line to be lighter so that's what the ternary is in the stroke. I used the data method to determine which would be light if it was a 0 or bold if it was a 1.

```
svg
.selectAll(".grid")
// border lines, 1 = dark border, 0 = light border
.data(gridPie([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]))
.append("line")
.attr("x1", 0)
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr(
  "y2",
  d =>
    Math.sin(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) *
    (radius - (d.data === 1 ? 0 : 75.5))
)
.attr(
  "x2",
  d =>
    Math.cos(d.startAngle - Math.PI / 2) *
    (radius - (d.data === 1 ? 0 : 75.5))
)
.attr("stroke", d => (d.data === 0 ? "#C8C8C8" : "#000"))
.attr("stroke-width", "0.1");
```